# Different results with and without a bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this SQL in SQL Developer I get a result with the correct 19 rows.

```
SELECT NAME, HEIGHT, HAIR_COLOR, AGE FROM PEOPLE WHERE AGE > 10
```

However, when I try to switch out 10 for a parameter a different amount of rows is returned, even though, when the prompt comes up, I enter "10"/ This is what the SQL looks like after I have the parameter set up.

```
SELECT NAME, HEIGHT, HAIR_COLOR, AGE FROM PEOPLE WHERE AGE > :age
```

However, even though I enter 10 it doesn't return the same result-set. Does anybody know why this might be the case?

Comment: what's the datatype of AGE, and also of :age ?

Comment: If your SQL, despite being identical, is not returning the same data from VB.net as it is from SQL Developer, then the only possible thing that can be wrong is the method in which you're binding to the variable. Can you post the relevant parts of your VB code?

Comment: @Ben well no, when I run both scripts in sql developer they arent they don't return the same

Comment: Ah, your tags were confusing; this is nothing to do with VB.net? So, is age a character column then? What exactly are you entering? A string or a number to the bind variable? And, can you provide sample data which accurately demonstrates your problem?